# Where did Mrs. Weasley make sandwiches in book three

Tags: harry-potter, chronology

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, the Weasleys, Harry, and Hermione were staying in the Leaky Cauldron the day before they boarded Hogwarts Express (1st September).

Still in the station, Mrs. Weasley handed out their sandwiches for them from out of her handbag.

> "I've made you all sandwiches. Here you are, Ron... no, they're not
>   corned beef... Fred? Where's Fred? Here you are, dear..."

I wonder where (and even when) did she manage to make them all sandwiches for their journey?

Possibilities are:

- She might have made them the day before journey, early morning at the Burrow.
- She might have requested Tom the innkeeper at the Leaky Cauldron let her use the kitchen for some time.

Comment: Been many a time I've made sandwiches in a hotel room for a packed lunch to explore a city with. Pre-siced everything (bread, cheese, ham) makes it pretty easy.

Comment: Being a pure vegetarian, I am unaware about process of making Sandwiches with Ham, Beef, etc. Thanks for comments and answers, though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While staying at the Cauldron Molly does some shopping. It seems likely that amongst her purchases were some sliced bread and fillings.

> At that moment Mrs Weasley entered the bar, **laden with shopping** and
>   followed by the twins, Fred and George, who were about to start their
>   fifth year at Hogwarts, the newly elected Head Boy, Percy, and the
>   Weasleys’ youngest child and only girl, Ginny.

Preparing food in her hotel room (to save money) seems like exactly the sort of money-saving idea that the notoriously thrifty Mrs Weasley would do.

Comment: Being a pure vegetarian, I am unaware about process of making Sandwiches with Ham, Beef, etc. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Ana - You can make a sandwich [out of almost anything](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PV3_UHG73oQ) :-)

Answer (score 2):

They were staying at the Leaky Cauldron, feet away from the most awesome magical market in the world, Diagon Ally. Since in the statement she says she has ***made*** the sandwiches, she may have purchased the bread and other materials from any shop in the ally, but most probably brought the materials from home (given they were Weasleys).

And compiling the sandwiches probably wouldn't need a kitchen, just a quick twirl of wand and all of them are ready!

Comment: Being a pure vegetarian, I am unaware about process of making Sandwiches with Ham, Beef, etc. Thanks for answer :)